# Struggling to open a file from an Objective-C path in ApplescriptObjC

Tags: objective-c, scripting, ms-word, applescript, applescript-objc

I am an experienced Cocoa programmer and an Applescript newbie. I need to program a Microsoft-based report generator. I started with the Applescript bridge and basically hit a wall with Word. I am now trying with ApplescriptObjC, and I am struggling like hell.

I am even stuck in the stupid step of opening a file when its path is reported by a method written in Objective-C. The objective-C class code is very simple (as a contrived example):

```
@implementation Reporter
- (NSString *)templatePath:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSString *fullPath = [self.currentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    return  fullPath;
}
@end
```

Side Note: the current directory is not the built app directory.
Here is one of my tries to use it:

```
on createReport()
    set my myReporter to Reporter's alloc()'s init()
    set WordApp to the application "Microsoft Word"
    set FinderApp to the application "Finder"
    set theWordTemplatePath to myReporter's templatePath:"Rapport.docx"
    set theWordTemplatePath to theWordTemplatePath as text
    tell FinderApp to open POSIX file theWordTemplatePath
end createReport
```

This one gets this error:

```
*** -[CMDAppDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:]: Finder got an error: Can’t make «class ocid» id «data optr0000000080B00E0080600000» into type integer. (error -1700)
```

I tried many variations, and despite many hours trying, I still can't have Word open my file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, forms like `POSIX file x` and `alias y` often have to be rewritten as `pPath as POSIX file` and `hfsPath as alias` in ASObjC.

Try this:

> ```
> set my myReporter to Reporter's alloc()'s init()
> set theWordTemplatePath to myReporter's templatePath:"Rapport.docx"
> set tPath to ((theWordTemplatePath as text) as POSIX file) as alias
> tell application "Microsoft Word" to open tPath
> ```

Comment: You are right that the solution is to write `open theWordTemplatePath as POSIX file` instead of `open POSIX file theWordTemplatePath`. You are wrong regarding the syntax however. The infix syntax with colons is correct.

Comment: Since a part of my answer is wrong, I edited my answer to remove this part